# Creating HTML/Javascript Modal with dynamic text

Tags: javascript, simplemodal, nodelist

I am learning Javascript and my project contains 3 buttons that open a modal. Everything works fine, however I want to reuse the modal and replace the modal text depending on which button is clicked.

My HTML is below:

```
    <body>
  <button class="show-modal" id="btn-1">Show modal 1</button>
  <button class="show-modal" id="btn-2">Show modal 2</button>
  <button class="show-modal" id="btn-3">Show modal 3</button>

  <div class="modal hidden">
    <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
    <h1>Modal Header Content</h1>
    <p class="hidden btn-1 text">
      This is modal 1 text content
    </p>
    <p class="btn-2 hidden text">This is modal 2 text</p>
    <p class="btn-3 hidden text">This is modal 3 text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay hidden"></div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

In my Javascript file, I have created variables to access various parts of the HTML:

```
    // get selector and store in variable for repeated use
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const btnCloseModal = document.querySelector('.close-modal');
//since button all have same class of show-modal, have to use querySelectorAll
const btnsOpenModal = document.querySelectorAll('.show-modal');
const text = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
console.log(text);
```

Then when I click on the button, the modal appears, but I cannot change the text. My thought was to get the button ID (which I get) and if that value is contained in the element class list, then remove the hidden class. But it doesn't work, so there is something I'm not understanding.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < btnsOpenModal.length; i++) {
  btnsOpenModal[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    // console.log(btnsOpenModal[i].id);
    console.log(btnsOpenModal[i]);
    let modalText = btnsOpenModal[i].id;

    console.log(modalText);
    if (text.classList.contains(modalText)) {
      text.classList.remove('hidden');
    }

    modal.classList.remove('hidden');
    overlay.classList.remove('hidden');
  });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Perhaps I cannot do this with javascript either, which is fine, but my instinct tell me it can be done.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are attempting to access the entirety of the `querySelectorAll` array instead of the individual element that you are interested in. See the code below for an example of a way to resolve this:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < btnsOpenModal.length; i++) {
  btnsOpenModal[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    let modalText = btnsOpenModal[i].id;

    if (text[i].classList.contains(modalText)) {
      text[i].classList.remove('hidden');
    }

    modal.classList.remove('hidden');
    overlay.classList.remove('hidden');
  });
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly!!

However, I just realized that now that it works, I have to add back the hidden class on the close modal function.

I can't access text[I] anymore sue to scope. This is what I have now:

function closeModalWindow() {
 
  modal.classList.add('hidden');
  overlay.classList.add('hidden');
}

Comment: @user2843365 You could add the hidden class to all of the `text` indices, no? If clicking the close button closes all the modals then you could iterate over all of them in the same looping manner as you do above

Comment: Absolutely - this is what I did and it works!

function closeModalWindow() {
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (!text[i].classList.contains('hidden')) {
      text[i].classList.add('hidden');
    }
  }